# PushKit not receiving the credentials

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I am working on an application which uses `PushKit` to deliver the notifications. And for some reason, the
`pushRegistry:didUpdatePushCredentials`
method is not getting called on most of the devices. Thus, I am unable to get the `PushKit` Credentials and the server is unable to send any notifications.

On some devices, I get the token every time I run the app. On other devices, I never get any token. Its weird. I have attached a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/suparngp/1109c80e2e90a2f48432)

Can some one help?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?